# Keyboard shortcut to import specific classes in Android Studio on Mac OSX

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a line of code like this:

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;;
```

When I click on the code, a tooltip appears asking me if I want to import `java.net.HttpURLConnection`. Yes, that's exactly what I want to do. However, when I press `ctrl + spacebar`, it correctly displays the list of classes to import but when I select the right one, it overrides the text there and looks like this:

```
HttpURLConnectionConnection urlConnection = null;
```

Now, I have to fix the class name. How can I import the class from the list of selections using keyboard shortcut without it causing the above issue?

Answer (score 0):

If the class name is hilighted when you do that, it will work correctly.  If you tap enter while the type ahead appears while typing, it will work correctly.  If the cursor is not in the name at all, it will work correctly.  This is only a problem if the cursor is in the middle of the name when you hit the button. Then you have to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Mac, you can place your cursor in the middle of the word and use the keyboard shortcut Option + Return.